# How to make Angular attribute Directive applied to only one DOM element at a time

Tags: css, angular, attributes, highlight, directive

> I do have the following Angular **attribute directive** which toggles
>   the css class *.highlighted* to its host upon click event.

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, Input, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[highlighted]'
})
export class HighlightedDirective {

  @Input('highlighted') isHighlighted = false;

  constructor() {
  }

  @HostBinding('class.highlighted')
  get cssClasses() {
    return this.isHighlighted;
  }

  @HostListener('click')
  toggle() {
    this.isHighlighted = !this.isHighlighted;
  }

}
```

> And applied to **every** div within *ngFor:

```
 <div *ngFor="let row of rows" highlighted>
    row
 </div>
```

> The css class is attached and removed correctly, but multiple divs can
>   be highlighted at a time.
>
> Given one existing div with *.highlighted* class already attached to it,
>   upon clicking inside another div, the highlighted directive should be
>   removed from the first div and attached to **last** clicked one
>   **ONLY**. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toggle or clear based on event target. Please check below code:

```
 import { Directive, HostBinding, Input,ElementRef,  HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[highlighted]'
})
export class HighlightedDirective {

constructor(private _elementRef : ElementRef) { }
  @Input('highlighted') isHighlighted = false;


  @HostBinding('class.highlighted')
  get cssClasses() {
    return this.isHighlighted;
  }

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
  public onClick(targetElement) {
    const clickedInside = this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
      if (clickedInside) {
          this.isHighlighted = !this.isHighlighted 
       }
      else{
        this.isHighlighted =false;
      }
  }

}
```